# How can i multiply or add the values of a dynamic javascript input field

Tags: javascript, laravel

The input field are been generated by `javascript`. I want to pick each value no matter how many input field I generate...so I can use the values for some calculations.

```
<form action="{{ route('addmorePost') }}" method="POST">
<div class="table-responsive">
                   <span id="result"></span>

                   <table class="table table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th width="55%">Sales Representative</th>
                      <th width="15%">Target per day</th>
                      <th width="15%">Monthly day</th>
                      <th width="10%"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+ </a> </th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
              <input type="text" name="target[]" class="form-control target" id="target" oninput="calc()">
                       </td>

                       <td><span id="sum1" onchange="add()">0</span> </td>

                       <td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">- </a> </td>
                      </tr>
                 </tbody>
                 <tfoot>


                    <tr>
                       <th>  
                       </th>
                       <th> Total</th>
                       <th><span id="sumx">0</span> </th> 
                     </tr>

                   </tfoot>


                   <script>                
                      function add() {

                      var ven1 = document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML;
                      var valuey = document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML || 0; 
                      console.log(ven1);
                      console.log(valuey);
                      document.getElementById('sumx').innerHTML = parseInt(ven1) + parseInt(valuey);

                    }
                   </script>




             </table>

              </button>

            </form>
```

BELOW IS THE `JAVASCRIPT` FOR GENERATED `INPUT FIELDS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){      
  var postURL = "http://localhost/bcwater/public/addmore";
  var i=1; 

  $('.addRow').on('click', function(){
    i++;
    addRow();
  });

  function addRow(){
     var tr = '<tr class="dynamic-added">'+
                '<td>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="target[]" id="target2" class="form-control" oninput="calc()" /> </td>'+
                '<td><span id="result1">0</span> </td>'+
                '<td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">- </a> </td>'+

              '</tr>';
          $('tbody').append(tr);
  }; 

  $('tbody').on('click','.remove', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });



});
```

THIS IS THE CODEI HAVE TRIED TO GET THE VALUES , MULTIPLY THEM BY 26 AND DISPLAY THE ANSWER ON sum1

```
    <script>


    function calc(){       
    var value1 = document.getElementById('target').value || 0;
    document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML = parseInt(value1 * 26);

    var value2 = document.getElementById('target2').value; 
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = parseInt(value2 * 26);


    var ven1 = document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML;
    var valuey = document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML || 0; 
    console.log(ven1);
    console.log(valuey);
    document.getElementById("products").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('sumx').innerHTML = parseInt(ven1) + parseInt(valuey);

    }

    </script>
```

PLEASE HELP!!!...WHAT AM I DOING WRONG

Comment: I need a way to auto change the ID (target2)..so that as i am adding more input field, the value changes and i can pick each value and multiply them as i want

Comment: I think you should create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to properly describe the current behaviour so people can know how to help out. Edit your question with the link once completed

Answer (score 1):

From your code every time you call `addRow()` the ID is always `target2`.
To auto change the ID, have a variable that holds the current ID and concatenate the string, you can make use of the `var i`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  var postURL = "http://localhost/bcwater/public/addmore";
  var i=1; 

  $('.addRow').on('click', function(){
    i++;
    addRow(i);
  });

  function addRow(i){
     var tr = '<tr class="dynamic-added">'+
            '<td>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="target[]" id="target' + i + '" class="form-control" oninput="calc()" /> </td>'+
            '<td><span id="result' + i + '">0</span> </td>'+ //This is modified to attach the current index to result
            '<td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">- </a> </td>'+

          '</tr>';
      $('tbody').append(tr);
  }; 

  $('tbody').on('click','.remove', function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

The `i` variable should always hold the index for the last row added

To multiply the values you have to make use of the same `i` variable, the function `calc()` should look like this, i suggest you rename `i` to something descriptive:

```
function calc(){       
    var value1 = document.getElementById('target').value || 0;
    document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML = parseInt(value1 * 26);

    for(var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        var value2 = document.getElementById('target' + j).value; 
        document.getElementById('result' + j).innerHTML = parseInt(value2 * 26); // This is to target the result span that corresponds to the input value
    }


    var ven1 = document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML;
    var valuey = document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML || 0; 
    console.log(ven1);
    console.log(valuey);
    document.getElementById("products").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('sumx').innerHTML = parseInt(ven1) + parseInt(valuey);

}
```

Comment: Thank u..i am able to get dynamic ID now by this code...id="target' + i + '"....can u please tell me or share a code for me to multiply the values of each ID?

Comment: Please see the edit above, note the change to `<span id="result">`

Answer (score 0):

Thank u..i was able to do it this way...after i increate the value of the id like this 
id="target' + i + '" and also span

so i use the below code to get the values manually...not the best option, but it solved my problem cos i dont need more than three input fields

```
        function calc(){     

        var value1 = document.getElementById('target').value || 0;
        document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML = parseInt(value1 * 26);

        var value2 = document.getElementById('target2').value; 
        document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = parseInt(value2 * 26);

        document.getElementById("products").disabled = false;


        var value2 = document.getElementById('target3').value; 
        document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = parseInt(value2 * 26);




        var ven1 = document.getElementById('sum1').innerHTML || 0;
        var valuey = document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML || 0; 

        var valuenew = document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML || 0; 



        document.getElementById('sumx').innerHTML = parseInt(ven1) + parseInt(valuey) + parseInt(valuenew);

        }

        </script>
```